# How to pass a URL parameter in with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I have a section on a webapp where the user can search a map for a set of locations and it all works properly but I want the text of the location to show up in the URL so that the user can copy it and share it and it will be the same search.

What is the best way to do this and can I do it with HTML or do I need to use Javascript?  I am using jinja2 as a templating engine and I am doing the back end in Python but that shouldn't have a big impact on this.  Basically I want them to be able to search for "New York City, NYC" and I want it to show up in the URL as something like

`www.url.com/map?location=new%20york%20city%20nyc`

Comment: are you doing searches on client side, because if search string is submitted to server it is no brainer just do a GET submit of form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is just to create a form:

```
<form action="/map" method="get">
<label>Search: <input type="search" placeholder="Search" name="location"></label>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

When you enter a search term into the input box and hit "Submit" the browser will make a request to `http://www.your-site.com/?q=Your%20Search%20Term` - and then you can get the argument from `request` and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: ah that was much easier than I thought.  I just needed to change the form from post to get and it worked.  thanks for the clear explaination

Answer (score 0):

```
document.location.hash = "some/values/moreValues";
```

And you can parse the hash when the page loads to display the content you need on the map